# Graph Theory - Prove complement graph has a diameter of at most $3$

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$ with a diameter of **at least** 3. Prove that the diameter of $\bar{G}$ (Complement graph) **is at most** 3.

I got stuck at the very beginning.. why those specific numbers? I mean, I would understand if the graph $H$ would have a diameter of $5$ and then $H = G \cup \bar{G}$ or something that contains somewhere the number $5$.. but nothing else is given..

I would appreciate your kind help! Thank you!

Comment: Title says "at least three", body says "at most three". Please edit for consistency.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry, I will fix it quickly, thank you!

Comment: I'm highly suspicious of this result. A graph of diameter at least $2$ is either a disconnected graph (with infinite diameter) or a graph that contains at least two points which are distance $2$ away, i.e. a graph for which not every vertex is adjacent, i.e. not a complete graph. If you remove an edge from a complete graph, you get a complement that has infinite diameter (so long as you started with at least $3$ vertices). Are we assuming $G$ and/or its complement are connected?

Comment: @user804886 Someone discussed about the infinite diameter of $\bar{G}$ and the professor said that if we would assume that $\text{diam}(G) > 2$ and not at least $2$. I hope that helps to understand the question, but I am still not sure how this helps.. I will update the question

Comment: Wait, strictly greater than $2$? Could you then clarify the conclusion is supposed to be $\operatorname{diam} \overline{G} < 3$? Or is it $\operatorname{diam} \overline{G} \le 3$ as I initially thought?

Comment: @user804886 I need to prove that if the $\text{diam}G \geq 3$ then $\text{diam} \bar{G} \leq 3$ (This is the question says, but It sounds odd, however I couldn't find any example that leads to contradiction

Comment: The diameter is the longest distance between $2$ vertices, but the distance of $2$ vertices is the minimal path length (not the maximum!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the diameter of graph is greater than 3 then the diameter of its complement graph is less than 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929512/if-the-diameter-of-graph-is-greater-than-3-then-the-diameter-of-its-complement-g) Note that the contrapositive of the statement you want to prove is "if diameter of $\overline G$ is greater than $3$, then diameter of $G$ is less than $3$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First simplifying assumption: assume the graph is connected, since if $G$ is disconnected then $\overline{G}$ has diameter two or less (so we don't need to worry about 'infinite' diameter nonsense).

Here's a hint: if a graph has diameter three or more, then it has two vertices $w$ and $z$ such that $d_G(w,z) = 3$. Consider a shortest path from $w$ to $z$, this will look like $w,x,y,z$, where the pairs $(w,y), (x,z)$ and $(w,z)$ are NOT adjacent in $G$.

A full proof is in the spoiler below (hover over to see it):

> Let $u$ and $v$ be vertices of $G$. Since $d_G(w,z) = 3$, it is not possible that $u$ is adjacent to both $w$ and $z$ in $G$. Thus $u$ IS adjacent to either $w$ or $z$ in $\overline{G}$. Similarly, $v$ is adjacent to either $w$ or $z$ in $\overline{G}$. Finally, $w$ and $z$ themselves are adjacent in $\overline{G}$, so $d_{\overline{G}}(u,v) \leq 3$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! one question though, why did you say that $\text{distance}_G(w,z) =3$ ? did you mean $\text{distance}_G(w,z) \geq 3$ ?

Comment: If the graph has diameter, say, 5, we can still always find two vertices ($w$ and $z$) that have distance exactly 3, but it doesn't matter much either way. The proof works the same whether you take $d(w,z) = 3$ or $d(w,z) \geq 3$.

Comment: Thank you sir!!

Comment: I have a question, why isn't it possible that $u$ is adjacent to both $z$ and $w$ ? what does that defy ? Thank you!

Comment: If $u$ is adjacent to both, then $z, u, w$ is a $z-w$ path of length two, which contradicts the fact that $d_G(z,w) \geq 3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have another question, I don't really see how the fact that $w$ and $z$ are adjacent in $\bar{G}$ says that $d_{\bar{G}}(u,v) \leq 3$ ... what does $w$ and $z$ have to do with $u$ and $v$ ??

Comment: Try draw out what happens in the complement graph. We get, for example, that $u$ is adjacent to $w$ and $v$ adjacent to $z$ in $\overline{G}$, so $u, w, z, v$ is a path of length three in $\overline{G}$.